# Export STL who to increase scale range

Tags: python, export

When exporting to STL blenders scale range is limited between 1000 and 0.01.

But in `script/addons/io_mesh_stl/__init__.py` it states:

```
102     global_scale = FloatProperty(
103             name="Scale",
104             soft_min=0.001, soft_max=1000.0,
105             min=1e-6, max=1e6,
106             default=1.0,
107             )
```

How can one increase what looks like a hard limit inside UI, to get the whole scale range? In particular, I wish to be able to export at scale 0.001 without resolving to change the global scene scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you posted is from the `ImportSTL` class. The `ExportSTL` class is defined below as follows:

```
    171    global_scale = FloatProperty(
    172        name="Scale",
    173        min=0.01, max=1000.0,
    174        default=1.0,
    175        )
```

You can simply change the values, save the file and restart blender like so:

```
    171    global_scale = FloatProperty(
    172        name="Scale",
    173        min=0.00001, max=1000.0,
    174        default=1.0,
    175        )
```

[image]

Comment: I must get blind for a moment, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, first time even seen this feature.. neat.